# Requirement to fetch RFCnumber value from below provided output and assign that value to a variable in Azure DevOps

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, azure-powershell

Below is the file output, need to fetch value of RFCnumber and assign that value to a variable:
{"d":{"__metadata":{"id":"https://cfdevmtl.ca10.services.xfs.cloud.sap:443/odata/SAP/ZSOL_AZU_API_SRV/ZSolmanRFCSet('1200021979')","uri":"https://cfdevmtl.ca10.services.xfs.cloud.sap:443/odata/SAP/ZSOL_AZU_API_SRV/ZSolmanRFCSet('1200021979')","type":"ZSOL_AZU_API_SRV.ZSolmanRFC"},"LongDescription":"Testï¿½Descriptionï¿½ofï¿½Change","ProductId":"100001575","ChangeTypeCd":"MHF","StepApproverPartnerid":"5048","OperationType":"new","ChangeType":"ZMCR","Status":"Success","ShortDescription":"Testï¿½Shortï¿½Description","CycleTypeId":"8200000083",**"RfcNumber":"1200021979"**,"Guid":"6CC2172E20B01EDD93A456C159D1BDE4","FuncUser":"5048","ExtrefNumber":"Extï¿½Refï¿½Number","message":"1200021979 created successfully"}}

I'm trying this code:
var=$(awk -F'"RfcNumber":"|","' 'NF>2{print $2;exit}' Input_file)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the value from a json file I would recommend using `jq` which would look like.

```
var="$(jq -r '.d.RfcNumber' file.json)"
```

- [stedolan.github.io/jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
- [unix.stackexchange.com/how-to-retrieve-values-from-json-object-using-awk-or-sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459805/how-to-retrieve-values-from-json-object-using-awk-or-sed)